# Having the relational schema write the following queries

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I started database a few weeks ago so im fairly new at this! WE have some homework to deliver in a few days related to writing some queries and i was hoping that if i posted my answer here maybe someone could help me understand if the way i tried to solve the exercises is right or wrong and in case of wrong maybe point out the mistakes so i could correct them! SO thanks in advance

The exercise goes like this:

*Given the following relational schema:*

**USER (SSN, NameU, SurnameU, City, YearOfBirth, UserType)**

**MOVIE (CodM, Title, Nation, Language, MovieStudio, Genre)**

**EVALUATION (SSN, CodM, Evaluation, Date)**

*Write the following queries in SQL language:*

a. For each user type, show the average evaluation given to movies produced by
"Marvel" (MovieStudio = "Marvel").

```
SELECT  U.USERTYPE , AVG(EVALUATION)

FROM    EVAUATION E,USER U,MOVIE M 

WHERE   E.SSN=U.SSN AND E.CODM=M.CODM AND MOVIESTUDIO='MARVEL' 

GROUP BY USERYPE
```

b.  For each user belonging to type "Expert" who has never evaluated movies of
genre "Horror" but has evaluated at least 3 movies of genre "Comedy", show name,
surname and the highest evaluation assigned to movies in language "Italian".

```
 SELECT USERTYPE,NAME,SURNAME,MAX(EVALUATION)

 FROM   USER U,MOVIE M,EVALUATION E

 WHERE  USERTYPE='EXPERT' AND U.SSN=E.SSN AND M.CODM=E.CODM 

        AND E.SSN NOT IN(SELECT E1.SSN

                         FROM EVALUATION E1, MOVIE M1

                         WHERE E1.CODM=M1.CODM AND GENRE='HORROR')

        AND E.SSN IN   (SELECT E2.SSN

                        FROM  EVALUATION E2, MOVIE M2

                        WHERE E2.CODM=M2.CODM AND GENRE='COMEDY'

                        GROUP BY EVALUATION

                              HAVING COUNT >=3)
         
        AND LANGUAGE='ITALIAN'

GROUP BY USERTYPE
```

THis was the best i could do at the moment! As i said im fairly new at this so i would apprechiate some assistance!

Comment: Please get out of the habit of using legacy comma joins and use ANSI joins. For example: `FROM    EVAUATION E INNER JOIN USER U ON (E.SSN=U.SSN) INNER JOIN MOVIE M ON (E.CODM=M.CODM) WHERE ...`

Answer (score 0):

**PLEASE DO NOT VOTE ON THIS ANSWER. I don't want rep points for basic queries. I used an answer because comments are suitable for helping the poster, who IMO has put significant work into their question and deserves a good answer.**

I agree 100% with @MT0 that ANSI joins are better, but if your professor hasn't yet taught them you should stick with the old-style joins. If your professor *has* taught ANSI joins, definitely use them instead. And when you're getting paid to write code, *always* use ANSI joins.

Here's the difference between old-style and ANSI:

```sql
-- Old style (your way)
SELECT U.USERTYPE, AVG(EVALUATION)
FROM EVALUATION E, USER U, MOVIE M
WHERE E.SSN=U.SSN AND E.CODM=M.CODM AND MOVIESTUDIO='MARVEL'
GROUP BY USERTYPE

-- ANSI (used by true professionals for the past 15-20 years)
SELECT U.USERTYPE, AVG(EVALUATION)
FROM EVALUATION E
JOIN USER U ON E.SSN = U.SSN
JOIN MOVIE M ON E.CODM = M.CODM
WHERE MOVIESTUDIO = 'MARVEL'
```

The ANSI style separates the join logic from the filtering logic, and once you're accustomed to it makes queries a lot easier to read.

Beyond that, the queries are solid. One minor nitpick that could lose you points when your work is graded: your aliasing is inconsistent.

```sql
SELECT U.USERTYPE, AVG(EVALUATION)
FROM EVALUATION E, USER U, MOVIE M
WHERE E.SSN=U.SSN AND E.CODM=M.CODM AND MOVIESTUDIO='MARVEL'
GROUP BY USERTYPE
```

The following columns are unaliased:

- `EVALUATION` (line 1)
- `MOVIESTUDIO` (line 3)
- `USERTYPE` (line 4)

All other columns *are* aliased. What makes this really jarring is that USERTYPE is aliased on line 1 but not on line 4. Be consistent. There will be exceptions now and then, but in this case it's best to alias *everything*.

Finally, kudos for showing your work. Too many homework questions on Stack Overflow just ask for the code. It's always appreciated when the question shows a high level of effort like yours does.

Comment: thanks a lot m8! As for the way i wrote the questions maybe will change in the future but for now this is the way the professors taught us to do it! I also have many examples here that do the same. But beside that thanks for dedicating some of your time to answer one of my questions! As you said i won't vote on the answer!

Comment: You're welcome! One other thing I meant to mention: on query #2 the `GROUP BY` should be `GROUP BY USERTYPE,NAME,SURNAME` if you're using Oracle. MySQL will let you get away with plain `GROUP BY USERTYPE` but most other databases (including Oracle) require all the non-aggregated values from the `SELECT`. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: If that is so in all cases than you just made GROUP BY  a hell of a lot easier ! Will do